# Column Integration per registry

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

I'm trying to get the results of a table ordered by different values in a column, but I want to show them in the same row... For example, my table looks like this.

```
PR_ID                       SOLUTION DESCRIPTION                                      
------------------------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
A1                                 1 Description 1                                     
A2                                 2 Description 2                                     
A3                                 3 Description 1                                     
A4                                 1 Description 3                                     
B1                                 1 Description 1                                     
B2                                 2 Description 2                                     
C1                                 3 Description 1                                     
C2                                 2 Description 2                                     

 8 rows selected
```

And I want the results to show something like this:

```
DESCRIPTION                     SOL_Up   SOL_Down   SOL_No_Valid
------------------------------ -------- ----------  -------------
Description 1                         2          0              3
Description 2                         0          3              0
Description 3                         1          0              0
```

I have the cases working, but when i tried to put them in the same row it sends me nulls, which I dont mind the nulls for 0's but I need them on the same row.

```
select 
description, Sol_Up, Sol_Down, Sol_No_Valid, count(1)
from
(
select description, 
case when Solution = 1 then 'Up' end Sol_Up,
case when Solution = 2 then 'Down' end Sol_Down,
case when Solution <= 0 or Solution >= 3 then 'No_Valid' end Sol_No_Valid 
from PRUEBAS_SOL
)
group by
description, Sol_Up, Sol_Down, Sol_No_Valid
order by Description;
```

But the results are nowhere near what I need...

```
DESCRIPTION                                        SO SOL_ SOL_NO_V   COUNT(1)
-------------------------------------------------- -- ---- -------- ----------
Description 1                                      Up                        2
Description 1                                              No_Valid          2
Description 2                                         Down                   3
Description 3                                      Up                        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      description

           ,count (case when Solution = 1          then 1 end) Sol_Up
           ,count (case when Solution = 2          then 1 end) Sol_Down
           ,count (case when Solution not in (1,2) then 1 end) Sol_No_Valid 

from        PRUEBAS_SOL

group by    description

order by    Description
;
```

Comment: Thank You! I didnt Know you could use the count(case)... Is there any book or page you could recommend?

Comment: This is a very old trick. The idea is to create an expression that returns values for the data the interests you and NULLs for the data that doesn't. Aggregation functions ignore NULLs.